# How to compile my own keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, compiling, keyboard-layout

I know that there is a community driven link to how to do this but it doesn't answer my question. Specifically because I'm using Gallium OS, and it isn't answering how to compile my keyboard. I have a svg and a json file of my keyboard and I'm not sure what to do next. How do I compile it? And once I'm done with that how do I add it? Gallium OS doesn't exactly have user friendly way of doing that, so some advanced help would be appreciated.

Comment: welcome to the XKB rabbithole, enjoy your stay https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xkb

Comment: Oh great, I already have a comment, at this rate I'll have an answer by the time the next millennium starts!